# MS Graph API Teams Call Record explained

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

## General Call Record Understanding

We're using the Microsoft Teams Graph API to analyse calls made through Microsoft Teams. We've setup a notification web hook that subscribes to the call records using the Graph API and then uses some more API calls to retrieve the call and user information for the received call. That's all working quite well (despite the time delay - but that's OK). What we struggle with ist the information retrieved from the [Call Record API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). We receive following data for example (UUIDs, names and phone numbers anonymised):

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords(sessions())/$entity",
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "version": 1,
    "type": "groupCall",
    "modalities": [
        "audio",
        "screenSharing"
    ],
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-10-18T11:16:03.5458861Z",
    "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:33.712657Z",
    "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.1331192Z",
    "joinWebUrl": null,
    "organizer": {
        "user": null,
        "acsUser": null,
        "spoolUser": null,
        "phone": {
            "id": "+49XXXXXXXX",
            "displayName": null,
            "tenantId": null
        },
        "guest": null,
        "encrypted": null,
        "onPremises": null,
        "acsApplicationInstance": null,
        "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
        "applicationInstance": null,
        "application": null,
        "device": null
    },
    "participants": [
        {
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": null,
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null,
            "user": {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Firstname Lastname",
                "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            }
        },
        {
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": null,
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null,
            "user": {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": null,
                "tenantId": null
            }
        },
        {
            "user": null,
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": {
                "id": "+49XXXXXXXX",
                "displayName": null,
                "tenantId": null
            },
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null
        },
        {
            "user": null,
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": {
                "id": "+49XXXXXXXX",
                "displayName": null,
                "tenantId": null
            },
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null
        },
        {
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": null,
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null,
            "user": {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": null,
                "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            }
        },
        {
            "acsUser": null,
            "spoolUser": null,
            "phone": null,
            "guest": null,
            "encrypted": null,
            "onPremises": null,
            "acsApplicationInstance": null,
            "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
            "applicationInstance": null,
            "application": null,
            "device": null,
            "user": {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": null,
                "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "sessions@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')/sessions",
    "sessions": [
        {
            "id": "403139dd-b5c1-457e-a5aa-b07e8c2bcc58",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:40.552989Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.1331192Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "b538ce68-cd12-4b22-b127-69b73a183e78",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:41.5686724Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.1331192Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "beb5c088-70f6-4b77-8a47-fbef0f3b6707",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:36.2402487Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.055049Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "user": null,
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": {
                        "id": "+49XXXXXXXX",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": null
                    },
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "c1fce6ee-8ac6-4680-a079-8384665aeba0",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:53.0392071Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.1331192Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "ce6e4e5d-77ff-421a-9b28-670dd691a119",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:36.2402487Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:52.4142559Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": "MicrosoftTeamsCallQueueService (20211014.1)",
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "modalities": [
                "audio"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:33.712657Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.0157168Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "user": null,
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": {
                        "id": "+49XXXXXXXX",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": null
                    },
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": "MicrosoftTeamsCallQueueService (20211014.1)",
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": null,
                        "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "e4f20c64-9343-4d67-b47b-9ba5e34ab373",
            "modalities": [
                "audio",
                "screenSharing"
            ],
            "startDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:55:51.8360806Z",
            "endDateTime": "2021-10-18T10:57:23.1331192Z",
            "failureInfo": null,
            "caller": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.participantEndpoint",
                "feedback": null,
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": "CallSignalingAgent (27/1.4.00.26376//;release_ktolskiy2/hook_R22.2021.22.01.56;releases/CL2021.R22)",
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "windows",
                    "productFamily": "teams"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "acsUser": null,
                    "spoolUser": null,
                    "phone": null,
                    "guest": null,
                    "encrypted": null,
                    "onPremises": null,
                    "acsApplicationInstance": null,
                    "spoolApplicationInstance": null,
                    "applicationInstance": null,
                    "application": null,
                    "device": null,
                    "user": {
                        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "displayName": "Firstname Lastname",
                        "tenantId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                    }
                }
            },
            "callee": {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.serviceEndpoint",
                "userAgent": {
                    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.callRecords.clientUserAgent",
                    "headerValue": null,
                    "applicationVersion": null,
                    "platform": "unknown",
                    "productFamily": "unknown"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To be able to get our heads around the data, we visualise the call sessions like this:

[image]
Our interpretation for this call is:

- `+49XXXXXXXX` calls the `Call Queue` call queue at 12:55:33
- at 12:55:51 `Firstname Lastname` picks up the call from the queue
- the call ends at 12:57:23.

Is this correct?

## Failure Info

Next thing we encountered is the [`failureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-failureinfo?view=graph-rest-1.0) information on a [call record session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-session?view=graph-rest-1.0). For some calls that are listed as failed in the Teams Call Record CSV export (administration user interface) we receive no failure info (but the total call duration is 0 seconds), while for others that are listed as successful in the CSV export we receive a failure info such as

```json
"failureInfo": {
    "reason": "Other",
    "stage": "callSetup"
}
```

These calls then have a sensible call duration.

Does anybody know of any issues with the failure information or what's the deal with this information?

We're analysing the calls rather extensively but currently we use our own interpretation of the call record sessions to determine what type of call it was, who picked up the call, who could have picked up the call, etc. But unfortunately there's not much information around (at least I could not find any) that describes the nature of these call record sessions: what they represent, what types of services we can encounter (bots, apps, etc.), which information you can extract from them and which not. Is just guessing at the moment for us.

I'd be really grateful for any hint, link, nudge in the right direction to get a better understanding of these call records.

Comment: Hi, I am now at the same point at you 3 years ago. I am searching for infos but the infos I got are insufficient infos . Do you get in the last 3 years. I would be happy about every helpfull info. Iam a little bit confuised about your callrecord,. Ho wyou get diplayname=null, the  id is  anonymised with '0', but null null doesn't look like anonymised.

Comment: I protect the question, to stop a current influx of "me too" answers by inexperienced users. (Comments are fine....)